Windows Dockerfile doesn't copy to app folder for base image
Sorry guys for stupid question i am new in Docker.
I tried advices from this title but it didn't help.
How to copy contents of folder to /app via dockerfile?
I have file that is added to csproj file from another project.
  <Content Include="..\Common.Utils\globalkafkasettings.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>

I want to copy this file to app folder for base image in docker container
Here is my dockerfile.
 # See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
    
    # Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
    # For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat
    
    # This stage is used when running from VS in fast mode (Default for Debug configuration)
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    #COPY ["bin/Debug/net8.0/globalkafkasettings.json", ""]
    COPY . /context
    
    EXPOSE 8080
    EXPOSE 8081
    COPY ["Common.Utils/globalkafkasettings.json", "/app/"]
    
    # This stage is used to build the service project
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
    COPY ["Common.Utils/Common.Utils.csproj", "Common.Utils/"]
    COPY ["Common.Utils/globalkafkasettings.json", "API/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "./API/API.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/API"
    RUN dotnet build "./API.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build
    
    # This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
    FROM build AS publish
    ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
    RUN dotnet publish "./API.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
    
    # This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]

Command COPY ["Common.Utils/globalkafkasettings.json", "/app/"] not working
I don't see this file in container.
But if i will choose another folder like this  COPY ["Common.Utils/globalkafkasettings.json", "/test/"] is working.
i don't understand why.

Shouldn't you be including the full path of Common utils that you want to copy

Was not able to repro. Can you please share a [mre]?

I decided to add kaska settings to appsettings.json to each project, and it is working sorry for wasting time
